# Control Operator Misused

Tags: php

I've got some PHP download script. Its last two lines are these:

```
header("Content-Length: ".  @filesize($filename));
@readfile($filename);
```

NetBeans warns in both lines "Error Control Operator Misused". May I ignore this warning or how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you know what the `@` symbol is actually doing in these lines?

Comment: Yes I read the PHP docu about it, but I don't know exception or stuff in PHP. So Clément Malet's answere hit the bull's-eye.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are already ignoring PHP warnings with `@`, I guess you could also ignore the NetBeans warnings.

More seriously, you should of course fix the problem :

- Remove all these `@` warning suppressors behind your function calls
- Handle or avoid errors from these functions properly : Check if `$filename` exists and if you have the right to read from it before trying to read the size and output its content

Comment: I expected this answere, but were not shure if it is the correct one. Thank you.

Comment: Storing and checking the return value of `readfile` is advised instead.
The file name and/or permissions might change between the check and the `readfile`.

Comment: The problem here is the open_basedir setting. There is no way you can check the file is inside allowed basedir (or at least I don't know it) without @ operator, custom error_handlers or manually parsing ini_settings. @ operator is the best solution here.

Comment: There are cases where `file_exists` and `filesize` called together cost more than just a `@filesize` in terms of performance. If something exists like `@` control error operator there must be a reson.

Comment: While using the `@` error control operator is inadvisable, I sometimes find that it is necessary. Conversely, just because something exists doesn't mean that you should use it - case in point, you should never use `eval`. Please note that most answers relating to this question are more of a matter of opinion and style, as any improvement in performance would be negligible. Regardless, If you deign to use`@`, it will make debugging your code much more difficult. Errors are typically thrown for a valid reason, and should be handled appropriately.